# Karma-Jasmine TypeError: this.ngRedux.getState is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I'm trying to run a test on one of my modules, which handles ngRedux.
while running the test, i get

> TypeError: this.ngRedux.getState is not a function

The test im running is a simple

```
it("should create component:", () => {
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
});
```

package.json

```
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
"redux-observable": "^0.12.2",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
"@angular/core": "4.3.6",
```

component code

```
 ...
let roleKinds = _.get(this.ngRedux.getState(), 'auth.user.Role', [])
        .filter(roleName => roles.indexOf(roleName) != -1);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my answer in this great post [Testing with Mocks & Spies](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/#_mocking_by_overriding_functions)

**UPDATE**

Adding my fixed code

```
 let spySomeService = {
    getData: () => {
    },
    getUserRole: () => {
    }
}

providers: [...
            {provide: SomeService, useValue: spySomeService},

 it("should create component:", () => {
    spyOn(spySomeService, 'getUserRole').and.returnValue("OK");
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
});
```